# firefox addon: cannot update tab URL using web extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'd like to know how to update URL addresses in Firefox using Web Extensions.

I'm trying to port a simple extension I've created with Chrome APIs to Firefox, but I don't really understand the tab URL mechanisms in Firefox.

This extension was made to switch between YouTube desktop/TV version with a click.

It works well on Chrome, but I don't know why it's not working on Firefox.

**UPDATE 1**: Placing most important code block related to the question:

```
chromeApi.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  var actionUrl = '';
  var tabUrl = tab.url;

  if (getCurrentPageVersion(tabUrl) !== undefined) {
    actionUrl = getConvertedActionUrl(tabUrl);
    if (actionUrl !== tabUrl) {
      chromeApi.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: actionUrl});
    }
  }

});
```

**Full source**

```
(function(chromeApi) {

  getCurrentPageVersion = function (tabUrl) {
    var ytValidRegex = /^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)/g;
    var ytValidStdPageRegex = /^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)?(\/watch\?v=).+$/g;
    var ytValidTvPageRegex = /^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)?(\/tv#\/watch(\/video)?\/(idle|control)\?v=).+$/g;

    if (!ytValidRegex.test(tabUrl)) {
      return undefined;
    } else if (ytValidStdPageRegex.test(tabUrl)) {
      return "std";
    } else if (ytValidTvPageRegex.test(tabUrl)) {
      return "tv";
    }

    return undefined;
  };

  getConvertedActionUrl = function (tabUrl) {
    var result = '';

    var shortStdYtUrlRegex = /\/watch\?v=.+/g;
    var shortTvYtUrlRegex = /\/tv#\/watch\/video\/(idle|control)\?v=.+/g;
    var shortStdYtUrlReplaceRegex = /\/watch\?v=/g;
    var shortTvYtUrlReplaceRegex = /\/tv#\/watch\/video\/(idle|control)\?v=/g;

    if (shortStdYtUrlRegex.test(tabUrl)) {
      result = tabUrl.replace(shortStdYtUrlReplaceRegex, '/tv#/watch/idle?v=');
    }

    else {
      result = tabUrl.replace(shortTvYtUrlReplaceRegex, '/watch?v=');
    }

    // YouTube standard website video url
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tRDQK2MtRs
    // YouTube TV url
    //https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=9tRDQK2MtRs
    return result;
  }

  onInit = function () {

  };

  // Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
  chromeApi.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var actionUrl = '';
    var tabUrl = tab.url;

    if (getCurrentPageVersion(tabUrl) !== undefined) {
      actionUrl = getConvertedActionUrl(tabUrl);
      if (actionUrl !== tabUrl) {
        chromeApi.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: actionUrl});
      }
    }

  });

  chromeApi.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if(!changeInfo.url) return; // URL did not change
    // Might be better to analyze the URL to exclude things like anchor changes
    var pageVersion = getCurrentPageVersion(tab.url);
    if (pageVersion === undefined) return;

    /* ... */
    chromeApi.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: pageVersion.toUpperCase(), tabId: tab.id});
  });

  chromeApi.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    var pageVersion = getCurrentPageVersion(tab.url);
    if (pageVersion === undefined) return;

    /* ... */
    chromeApi.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: pageVersion.toUpperCase(), tabId: tab.id});
  });

})(chrome);
```

If you pay attention, the core functionality happens on the `chromeApi.browserAction.onClicked` event, whenever you click the add-on/extension button.

The extension updates correctly between each YouTube version in Chrome, but in Firefox, this one redirects to YouTube TV once and never goes back to the desktop version no matter how many times you click on it.

But there's something weird in Firefox: browser history is updated correctly whenever the `tab.update` method is called, but it redirects to the TV version by itself again.

**IMPORTANT**: Both Firefox/Chrome extensions are using the `currentTab` permission, so it's not an extension issue by itself.

[Extension on GitHub](https://github.com/fori920/youtube-tv-switcher)

**UPDATE 2 (2018-11-25)**: I've updated the source code based on previous feedback

Comment: Side question: Why are you using the pattern `(function(chromeApi) {})(chrome);`? I note that you are only using `chromeApi.*` in some places in your code, with an number of calls to `chrome.*` within the function.

Comment: @Makyen I'll try to remove them first. I was having some badge update issues with Chrome, however It could be my fault in somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Please show your actual code. Where is this block of code located? Is it located within something else that calls this block? Is it your background script? You have a comment that says `// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.` for this entire section, but you call `chromeApi.browserAction.onClicked.addListener()` with an anonymous function from within this code. Does that mean you're adding an additional listener each time the `browserAction` button is clicked? Or, is this the setup code for your only one `browserAction` onClicked listener?

Comment: It's the setup for one `onClicked` listener addition (at least that what I actually expects to do) Also, comments in my code are a mess, so I'll try organize them as much as possible. And this is the actual code as well.